# Fluxx - When should I carry out actions / use keepers?

Tags: fluxx

At the start of a turn before drawing cards? Or at the end?

(Zombie Fluxx in this case, but common to all variants of Fluxx I think?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always draw cards before playing cards.

EDIT:

The general turn outline is:

1. Draw cards (in following the current draw rule)
2. Play cards (in following the current play rule)
3. Discard cards (to follow the 'card limit' rule, if applicable)

Comment: So, to confirm, If I want to, say, kill a zombie with a weapon, I have to do that the Play cards section (within the limits?). I can't do it after playing, for example, 4 cards I've just drawn?

Comment: @Jon: I've only played Zombie fluxx once, so I'm a little unsure of exact details.  However, I'm not sure what you mean by "after playing, 4 cards I've just drawn".  Drawing comes before playing.

Answer (score 2):

Zombie Fluxx allows you to kill Zombies during your turn, after your draw.  If you look at the rulebook there is a panel which starts "It's your turn.  Start by drawing 2 cards."  During the course of that example turn several zombies are killed by dint of the Zombie Season new rule and various Weapon keepers... but these are all completely free actions.  After that the player still has 2 plays (Draw 2 and Play 2 are in effect) to do other cool stuff.

Killing zombies, easy when you know how!